# How can I add a datasource to a UIMap method instead of a Test Method (VS 2010 Coded UI Test)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, datasource, coded-ui-tests

I have a 2010 Coded UI Test that performs some actions against a website.  I am able to add a datasource to a "Test Method" which loops the entire method once per record.

But, what I really want to do is loop only a portion of the test which is just a single recorded method in the UIMap.

Let's say the test method looks something like this:

```
//[DataSource("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.XML", "|DataDirectory|\\TestCommunities.xml", "Community", DataAccessMethod.Sequential), DeploymentItem("Tests\\WebTests\\DataSources\\TestCommunities.xml"), TestMethod]        
public void LoginCreateCommunities()
    {
        this.UIMap.LoginAdmin();
        //this.UIMap.CreateCommunityParams.UIItem0EditText = TestContext.DataRow["CommunityName"].ToString();
        this.UIMap.CreateCommunity();
        this.UIMap.LogoffClose();
    }
```

It's only UIMap.CreateCommunity() that I want to loop the datasource.  I do not want all 3 methods to execute per record in the datasource, which is what happens when I attach the datasource to the test method (the portion commented out above).

Is there a way to achieve what I'm trying to do here?

Thanks.

Comment: Let me see, I'll ask this another way... without hand-coding everything (I'd like to use some of the built-in CUIT magic), am I able to loop only a <u>portion</u> of a Coded UI test method via a datasource (not the entire coded test method).

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the ClassInitialize and ClassCleanup methods. You place it in the     **#region Additional test attributes** area at the bottom. So for you it'd look something like:

```
    #region Additional test attributes

    [ClassInitialize]
    static public void ClassInit(TestContext context)
    {
        Playback.Initialize();
        try
        {
            sharedTest.LoginAdmin();
        }
        finally
        {
            Playback.Cleanup();
        }

    }


    [ClassCleanup]
    static public void ClassCleanup()
    {
        Playback.Initialize();
        try
        {
            sharedTest.LogoffClose();
        }
        finally
        {
            Playback.Cleanup();
        }
    }

    #endregion
```

Comment: Would you kindly explain what `Playback.Initialize()` and `Playback.Cleanup()` do? Should a call to `Initialize` be conditional upon the `IsInitialized` property? Why is `Playback.Cleanup()` called immediately after the action is done, and not at the very end of the test suite?

Comment: what is the "sharedTest" here?

Comment: This is an old answer but the Playback.Initialize() and Playback.Cleanup() run before and after the test itself. The 'sharedTest' in this case is a another test method that I'm calling. It's been a couple of years since I wrote my answer and have since moved on to using Selenium WebDriver (C#) instead with Visual Studio 2012 - which works way better for me. Sorry if this doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

first you have to define a new UIMap in your codedUI class

```
[CodedUITest]
public class CodedUITest1
{
    static private UIMap sharedTest = new UIMap();

    ....

    [ClassInitialize()]
    static public void ClassInit(TestContext context)
    {
        Playback.Initialize();
        try
        {
            sharedTest.RecordedStartApp();
        }
        finally
        {
            Playback.Cleanup();
        } 
    }

    [ClassCleanup()]
    static public void ClassCleanup()
    {
        Playback.Initialize();
        try
        {
            sharedTest.RecordedCloseApp();
        }
        finally
        {
            Playback.Cleanup();
        } 
    }
}
```